# trouble with ruby passenger

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, mamp

when i paste this code in MAMP's httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Volumes/Private/ajsie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/passenger-2.2.14/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Volumes/Private/ajsie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/passenger-2.2.14
PassengerRuby /Volumes/Private/ajsie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
```

then MAMP wont start.

i have checked that the paths are correct.

does anyone else have the same problem with MAMP and passenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also getting this issue with MAMP and passenger. Is apache spitting anything useful in the error logs. I'm getting:

```
[Wed Jun 16 16:07:39 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jun 16 16:07:39 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jun 16 16:07:39 2010] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 16 16:09:29 2010] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I'm also assuming when you installed passenger-install-apache2-module it didn't come up with any errors about finding Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because passenger has been "compiled" against the osx built-in apache headers. If you're using MAMP, you should compile it against MAMP's built-in apache headers.

I don't know how to specify which apache I'm using when I install it:

```
$sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

> Welcome to the Phusion Passenger
>   Apache 2 module installer, v2.2.11.
>
> This installer will guide you through
>   the entire installation process. It
>   shouldn't take more than 3 minutes in
>   total.
>
> Here's what you can expect from the
>   installation process:
>
> 1. The Apache 2 module will be installed for you.
> 2. You'll learn how to configure Apache.
> 3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.
>
> Don't worry if anything goes wrong.
>   This installer will advise you on how
>   to solve any problems.
>
> Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to
>   abort.
>
> ---
>
> Checking for required software...
>
> - GNU C++ compiler... found at
>     /usr/bin/g++  * Ruby development
>     headers... found  * OpenSSL support
>     for Ruby... found  * RubyGems... found
>
>   - Rake... found at /usr/bin/rake  * rack... found  * Apache 2... found at
>       /usr/sbin/httpd  * Apache 2
>       development headers... found at
>       /usr/sbin/apxs